# Creating a bitmap from byte[]

Tags: java, android, image, image-processing, bitmap

I'm trying to construct a `Bitmap` from a provided `byte[]` on my Android device.

The `byte[]` is being sent from my computer which has a normal Java program running as a server. Once my Android device connects, the Java program starts to grab `BufferedImage`s from my webcam and then sends the contents of the `BufferedImage` as a `byte[]` to my Android device.

This is how I'm sending the array of data from my computer to my Android device...`frame` is a `BufferedImage` which always is of size 176x144.

```
int[] pixels = frame.getRGB(0, 0, frame.getWidth(), frame.getHeight(), null, 0, 176);

for (int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++) // rgb values only
{
    int r = pixels[i] & 0xFF;
    int g = (pixels[i] >> 8) & 0xFF;
    int b = (pixels[i] >> 16) & 0xFF;
    pixels[i] = new Color(r, g, b).getRGB();
}


// convert int[] into byte[] so it can be sent over the stream
ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(pixels.length * 4);
byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
IntBuffer intBuffer = byteBuffer.asIntBuffer();
intBuffer.put(pixels);
byte[] toSend = byteBuffer.array();

// write to client using already setup BufferedOutputStream
bosToClient.write(toSend, 0, toSend.length);
bosToClient.flush();
```

And this is how I'm reading the bytes on the Android device and trying to construct a `Bitmap`... `imageBytes` is the `byte[]` my device recieved from the computer.

```
// convert to the original int[] of pixels
ByteBuffer byteBufferAfter = ByteBuffer.wrap(imageBytes);
byteBufferAfter.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
IntBuffer intBufferAfter = byteBufferAfter.asIntBuffer();
int[] framePixels = new int[intBufferAfter.limit()];
intBufferAfter.get(framePixels);

// Create bitmap
Bitmap frameBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(framePixels, 0, 176, 176, 144, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
frameBitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(IntBuffer.wrap(framePixels));
```

However this results in images that are clearly rendered incorrectly.

The original `BufferedImage`'s I'm sending as `byte[]`s have the following properties...

```
ColorModel: #pixelBits = 24 
numComponents = 3 
color space = java.awt.color.ICC_ColorSpace@50cbc42f 
transparency = 1 
has alpha = false 
isAlphaPre = false

 minX = 0
 minY = 0
 width = 176
 height = 144
 sampleModelTranslateX = 0
 sampleModelTranslateY = 0
 numBands = 3
 numDataElements = 3
 parent = null
```

The number of `scanlines` is 528 if that provides any help.

What is going wrong with the decoding? I've tried almost everything and can't figure it out.

Also, I MUST use the `byte[]` to send the image. I can't use `BitmapFactory.decodeStream` (its way too slow)

Screenshots of what my device outputs...

[image: working colour]

[image: working colour 2]

Comment: To drill it down: Did you compare the color values on both sides, i.e. does the basic transmission work as expected? If so, put a reference image (coloured 2x2 grid seems a good idea) to more closely identify the nature of the problem. High level debugging usually leaves you stuck with "doesn't work the way I want it to"

Comment: @dhike I will do that now and report back.

Comment: @dhke I will respond in 90 minutes. Sorry.

Comment: @dhke I can confirm that the pixels are getting correctly sent across to the android device. Both the server and device int[] representing the image pixels have the same data inside.

Comment: Only just guessing here, but the BufferedImage you are sending has 24 bits per pixel, while you are decoding the image with the Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888 profile which includes alpha (total 32 bits per pixel). Try decoding it with the correct RGB profile, let's see what happens

Comment: I've modified my code so now on the server side for every pixel a new integer value is created for it using `new Color(r, g, g).getRGB()` this seems to have removed the blue tint but I still have the choppiness issue. I will update the main post with a screenshot of what I get on my device now.

Comment: @LugaidVandroiy With the modification mentioned in my previous comment, ARGB_8888 seems to actually decode the image colours correctly! Check the new screenshot